# Displaying message dialog on UnhandledException

Tags: c#, uwp

In my App I want to display a message dialog whenever there is any Unhandled exception. But it seems that dialog message is not appearing when Unhandled exception is throw, Is it valid to display message popup? Also in MSDN documentation I didn't find much info for it.

Below is the test code which I am using:

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    this.UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
}

private async void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Unhandled Execption", "Exception");
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried call synchronous version of `Dialog.Show`?

Comment: Your app might get terminated as you're using an async event handler

Comment: "Is it valid to display message popup?" - What's your definition of "valid"? Presenting a message about an unexpected error may be convenient for the user in the sense that the app doesn't just close "without reason". So _imho_ it's a good idea. I'd add information about what to do from there (contact support, send logs ... ).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to make sure to set the `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.Handled` property to true before you display the `MessageDialog`. If the `Handled` property is not set, the OS will terminate the app immediately after the event handler returns, which in this case is as soon as the execution gets to the `await dialog.ShowAsync()`. Because the app is immediately terminated, you don't even get the chance to see the dialog.

The ideal implementation would look like this:

```
private async void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Unhandled Execption", "Exception");
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Once the user confirms the `MessageDialog`, the app is programmatically terminated. It is a good course of action because after the unhandled exception we likely don't know what state the app is in and probably can't recover.
 You could also perform some sort of logging or offer the user to send an error report.

Comment: But there is not way to prevent the app from continued execution at that point?

Comment: Yes, using the `Application.Exit()` call you kill it forcibly

Comment: Yes but won't the app execution continue to run until the user closes the dialogue? So if an unhandled exception is thrown in a task it will get caught by your handler but other parts of the app will continue to run until the user closes the dialogue.

Comment: That is actually true, good point. But user won't be able to interact with the app as the dialog is modal. So it depends on whether there is something that could cause a problem for you in this case.

Comment: Setting the e.Handled did not prevent VS 2017 from showing its own dialog as well as invoking the JIT Debugger process attach prompt.

Comment: Great answer. Only thing I recommend is that you use a ContentDialog; MessageDialog is more of a legacy Windows 8 component.